# Using Hibernate, how do I check if the User trying to login has a registered account in the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, authentication, dao

I'm new to Hibernate and Servlets, I'm working on a very small project where users are able to book rooms in a hotel.

I'm able to signup/create an account successfully, but I'm not able to login.

I've tried using the Criteria Queries in the DAO class but it fails with a *java.lang.ClassCastException*.

The username and password from the *login.jsp* page are sent to the *Login servlet* where a new DAO object is created and the extracted username and password is passed to it's method.

The DAO uses Criteria Queries to check if the user is present in the database and returns a boolean value, the *Login servlet* checks the returned boolean value and redirects if it's true.

*The Login Servlet:*

```
String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

       try 
       {
             UserLoginDAO uldao = new UserLoginDAO();
             boolean login = uldao.checkUserLogin(uname, pass);
            if(login==true)
            {
                response.sendRedirect("room.jsp");

            }
            else
            {
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }

            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

*The DAO class:*

```
public boolean checkUserLogin(String uname,String pass)
    {
        boolean login=false;
        try {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
            SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sf.openSession();
            Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

            CriteriaBuilder builder =   session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<String[]> criteriaquery = builder.createQuery(String[].class);
            Root<User> root = criteriaquery.from(User.class);

            Path<String> usernamePath = root.get("userName");
            Path<String> passwordPath = root.get("password");

            criteriaquery.multiselect(usernamePath,passwordPath);


            Query<String[]> query = session.createQuery(criteriaquery);
            List<String[]> list =   query.list();

            for(String[] s:list)
            {

                if(s[0].equals(uname) && s[1].equals(pass))
                {
                    login=true;
                }

                else
                {
                    login=false;
                }
            }

            tr.commit();



        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return login;

    }
```

When I try to login, the web browser redirects to the Login servlet and stops with the *java.lang.ClassCastException*. Most of the tutorials online use jdbc instead of Hibernate. Is there an easy way to implement login with Hibernate?

Comment: Don't catch HibernateException. Catching it just hides a bug in your code. If your question is about an exception, then post its exact and complete stack trace. It contains what we need to know to understand why and where it's thrown.

Comment: Note that building a new session factory every time you receive a request is really really not something you should do. This takes a **lot** of time and resources. it must be done once, and only once. I really suggest you read the Hibernate user guide. Using a criteria query although your query is completely static is also overkill. use JPQL. And don't load all the users from the database to find the one with the given username. Use a query which find **the** user with that username.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into this issue and it seems like it is not returning the data in `String[]` from `query.list()` although it should be doing that according to the API documentation.

**Alternative**

As an alternative you can use the `Tuple` class or the `Object[]`

1. The code below is using the `Tuple`
2. Another important point is that a username is expected to be unique that will be used for login purposes. Therefore you don't need to use the `query.list()` rather `query.getSingleResult()` is ok to use.
3. And also you need to add the where condition so that only the user record specific to the user and pass you have passed to this method are retrieved from the database. Without the where method you will get all the list of users and then you are going through the loop to find the required user. This is not a good approach.

   ```
   public boolean checkUserLogin(String uname, String pass) {

       boolean login = false;

       try {


           Configuration cfg = new 
               Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(User.class);

           SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

           Session session = sf.openSession();

           Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();


           CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

           CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaquery = builder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
           Root<User> root = criteriaquery.from(User.class);

           Path<String> usernamePath = root.get("username");
           Path<String> passwordPath = root.get("password");

           criteriaquery.multiselect(usernamePath, passwordPath);

           criteriaquery.where(builder.equal(root.get("username"), uname), builder.equal(root.get("password"), pass));

           Query<Tuple> query = session.createQuery(criteriaquery);

           Tuple _userRec = query.getSingleResult();
           System.out.println("user -> " + _userRec.get(0, String.class) + ", pass -> " + _userRec.get(1, String.class));

           if (_userRec != null) {
               login = true;
           }

           tr.commit();

       } catch (HibernateException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return login;
   }
   ```